# JsConfig.BeginScope and custom type serializer

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-text

JsConfig.BeginScope allows me to customize serialization for specific operation without affecting global config. However, how do I provide custom SerializeFn for specific type for the duration of the scope? It seems JsConfig< T > is always static and ignores the scope completely?

Answer (score 0):

Configuration on `JsConfig<T>` is only configurable statically and is not an available option on [JsConfigScope](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/JsConfigScope.cs).

Comment: Any suggestions then on how can I write a library that uses JsConfig< T > without messing up the config of anyone using the library? Or do I need to manually modify Servicestack.Text to add such functionality?

Comment: @Sumrak JsConfig<T> is only static and not scopable.